# Write down an explicit tensor of border rank $r$ in $\mathbb{C}^r \otimes \mathbb{C}^r \otimes \mathbb{C}^r$ with rank greater than $r$

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

This question is from the text *Geometry and Complexity Theory*, from J.M. Landsberg. Before start talking about the question, I think it is good to show the definition of border rank. Consider a tensor $T \in \mathbb{C}^r \otimes \mathbb{C}^r \otimes \mathbb{C}^r$. Then the *border rank* of $T$ is the minimum $r$ such that $T$ can be arbitrarily approximated by tensors of rank $r$.

In this discussion we asume $r > 1$ is integer. In general, the limit of tensors of rank $r$ may not be a tensor of rank $r$. An example is given in the text (I changed a little the notation):

Let $x_i, y_i \in \mathbb{C}^r$ be linearly independent vectors, for $i = 1,2,3$. Then the sequence of rank 2 tensors

$$T_n = n\left( x_1 + \frac{1}{n} y_1 \right) \otimes \left( x_2 + \frac{1}{n} y_2 \right) \otimes \left( x_3 + \frac{1}{n} y_3 \right) - nx_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes x_3 $$

converges to the rank 3 tensor

$$T = x_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes y_3 + x_1 \otimes y_2 \otimes x_3 + y_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes x_3. $$

The author says that $T$ is a rank $3$ tensor with border rank $2$. With this example in mind I tried to come up with the following idea:

Let $x_i, y_i \in \mathbb{C}^r$ be linearly independent vectors, for $i = 1, \ldots, r$. Consider the sequence

$$T_n = n\left( x_1 + \frac{1}{n} y_1 \right) \otimes \left( x_2 + \frac{1}{n} y_2 \right) \otimes \left( x_3 + \frac{1}{n} y_3 \right) - nx_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes x_3 + $$
$$ + n\left( x_2 + \frac{1}{n} y_2 \right) \otimes \left( x_3 + \frac{1}{n} y_3 \right) \otimes \left( x_4 + \frac{1}{n} y_4 \right) - nx_2 \otimes x_3 \otimes x_4 + \ldots$$
$$ \ldots + n\left( x_{\frac{r}{2}} + \frac{1}{n} y_{\frac{r}{2}} \right) \otimes \left( x_{\frac{r}{2}+1} + \frac{1}{n} y_{\frac{r}{2}+1} \right) \otimes \left( x_{\frac{r}{2}+2} + \frac{1}{n} y_{\frac{r}{2}+2} \right) - nx_{\frac{r}{2}} \otimes x_{\frac{r}{2}+1} \otimes x_{\frac{r}{2}+2}$$

for $r$ even. The $T_n$ is a sum of $r$ rank 1 tensor, so $T_n$ has rank $r$. Furthermore, we have that $T_n$ converges to

$$T =  x_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes y_3 + x_1 \otimes y_2 \otimes x_3 + y_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes x_3 + $$ 
$$ + x_2 \otimes x_3 \otimes y_4 + x_2 \otimes y_3 \otimes x_4 + y_2 \otimes x_3 \otimes x_4 + \ldots $$
$$\ldots +  x_{\frac{r}{2}-2} \otimes x_{\frac{r}{2}-1} \otimes y_\frac{r}{2} + x_{\frac{r}{2}-2} \otimes y_{\frac{r}{2}-1} \otimes x_\frac{r}{2} + y_{\frac{r}{2}-2} \otimes x_{\frac{r}{2}-1} \otimes x_\frac{r}{2}$$

which is a sum of $3(\frac{r}{2}-2)$ rank 1 tensors, so $T$ has rank $3(\frac{r}{2}-2)$.

I have some concerns about this "solution"., which I'm going to list here.

**1)** I'm not sure if the tensors $T_n$ really have rank $r$, maybe there is a way to reduce the number of terms which I'm not aware of. The same goes to $T$.

**2)** In order to have $3(\frac{r}{2} - 2) > r$ we need $r > 12$. This restriction indicates my solution is wrong someway.

**3)** Finally, to work with $r$ odd I need to add one last term in an artificial way. This also makes me think this whole idea is not good.

Well, I need some directions here. To be honest I'm new in the study of tensors, so any help with nice explanations are very welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: Your $T_n$ has $r-4$ summands, not $r$. But a similar thing could work.

Comment: To prove your tensor is not of rank $r$, you need some lower bound, for example one can use substitution method.

Comment: @VladimirLysikov You are right about the summands, I'm going to fix it now. Also I'm not aware of how to use substitution method, in fact, I don't even know what is this method for tensors...

Comment: I see, at least in the draft available online this is the first exercise after the definition of border rank. It may be there just to show students by experience that the things are complicated. I'll write an answer with some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to prove that the border rank is exactly $r$ and not less is the flattening lower bound. You can see a tensor $T \in A\otimes B\otimes C$ as a linear map $T\colon A^* \to B\otimes C$. If $T$ has tensor rank $\leq r$, than this map also has rank $\leq r$, and we can take the limits to talk about border rank. (Landsberg discusses it in the section "Our first lower bound").

To show that the rank is more than $r$, we need to do something slightly more complicated. Again look at $T\colon A^* \to B\otimes C$. If $T$ has rank $r$, then you can say many things about values $T(\alpha)$ for various $\alpha \in A^*$. Try to construct your tensor in such a way that some of these things cannot hold.

Comment: I accepted this answer although it didn't really helped...it's just that I gave up this problem. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V = \mathbb{C}^r$ have basis $\{x_1,\dotsc,x_r\}$. Consider the tensor
$$
\begin{split}
  T &= x_1^2 x_2 + x_3^3 + x_4^3 + \dotsb + x_r^3 \\
    &= x_1 \otimes x_1 \otimes x_2 + x_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes x_1 + x_2 \otimes x_1 \otimes x_1 + x_3 \otimes x_3 \otimes x_3 + \dotsb + x_r \otimes x_r \otimes x_r .
\end{split}
$$
where I have used polynomial (symmetric tensor) notation, I hope it is clear how to make it correspond with usual tensors.

As a tensor, this is written as a sum involving $r+1$ terms ($3$ for the first $2$ basis elements, plus $r-2$ more for $x_3,\dotsc,x_r$). Therefore $T$ has rank less than or equal to $r+1$.

I claim that $T$ has rank equal to $r+1$ and border rank equal to $r$.

First,
$$
  T = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(x_1+t x_2)^3-x_1^3}{3t} + x_3^3 + \dotsb + x_n^3
$$
(again using polynomial notation for convenience), which shows that $T$ has border rank less than or equal to $r$.

A lower bound for border rank is not too hard. For example there is a lower bound given by flattening rank, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280554/is-a-flattening-rank-a-lower-bound-for-the-border-rank. To be a little bit explicit, we get a map from, say, $V^* \otimes V^* \to V$. Say $V^*$ has dual basis $\{y_1,\dotsc,y_r\}$. The induced map $V^*\otimes V^* \to V$ (also denoted $T$ by slight abuse of notation) is given by
$$
  T(y_i \otimes y_j) = x_1(x_1(y_i)\cdot x_2(y_j)) + x_1(x_2(y_i)\cdot x_1(y_j)) + \dotsb + x_r(x_r(y_i) \cdot x_r(y_j)) .
$$
So $T(y_1 \otimes y_2) = x_1$, $T(y_1 \otimes y_1) = x_2$, and for $3 \leq i \leq r$, $T(y_i \otimes y_i) = x_i$. This shows that this induced map is onto. So it has rank $r$. Therefore the tensor $T$ has border rank greater than or equal to $r$, see the linked MO answer for an explanation why.

Here is one idea for how to get a lower bound for the tensor rank of $T$. First observe that the tensor given by the first three terms of $T$ (corresponding to $x_1^2 x_2$) is precisely the first example you started with, so it has rank $3$. (One way to see that it has rank $3$ is here [Find the rank of the tensor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905543/find-the-rank-of-the-tensor).) And by a special case of Strassen's conjecture, each time we add a term $x_i \otimes x_i \otimes x_i$, with $x_i$ linearly independent from all the previously used vectors, then we in fact add $1$ to the rank. Unfortunately I am having trouble finding a citation for that at the moment. Please let me know if you're still interested, I will be happy to look again.